# REST API Filter by LoginName from user list not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, jsom

I have a list A, which has a column `owner` of type "Person or Group". I am using REST API to query this list(using jquery).

I would like to use column `owner` to filter records by username. I have a user/group picker from which I get username in this format: `i:0#.f|membership|username`

The query I am trying is:

```
http://site//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('A')/items?$select=column1,column2$filter=owner/LoginName eq 'i:0#.f|membership|username'
```

But I am getting error 500 with message

> "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields."

I would like to know what I am donig wrong

Also is there any other way to filter using username?

Answer (score 4):

For lookup columns, you have to use `$expand`. So the query URL should look like

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('A')/items?$select=column1,column2&$filter=owner/LoginName eq 'i:0#.f|membership|username'&$expand=owner
```

There are some special character in `i:0#.f|membership|username`, so you have to encode it before passing in query URL.

```
encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|username')
```

#Modified Query URL

```
"_api/web/lists/getbytitle('A')/items?$select=column1,column2&$filter=owner/LoginName eq "+encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|username')+"&$expand=owner"
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer Atish. As it turns out I was using wrong column name from user list. User list has column `Name` which has names stored in `i:0#.f|membership|username` this format

Answer (score 1):

The special characters coming in the REST api query need to be encoded before using.

The javascript out-of-box encodeURIComponent() method can be used.

`encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|vikasbansal@domain.com')`

In my scenario, encodeURI() method didn't worked properly.

Use the updated complete REST query given below.

```
https://sp2013/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('A')/items?$select=column1,column2$filter=owner/LoginName eq + encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|vikasbansal@domain.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetListData(select)
{
 var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
 var listname = "MyListName";
 var currentUserId=_spPageContextInfo.userId; //is a user number Then needs to use /ID
 var url = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=ID,Name,Title,MyUserField/ID&$filter=substringof('"+currentUserId+"',MyUserField/ID)&$expand=MyUserField/ID";


$.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {

        var items = data.d.results;
         alert(items.length);

        for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {           
            var item=items[i];

            //console.log(item.Title);
        }       
     },
     error: function (data) {  
                           alert("error");     
                             }
 });
}
```